# Error: column is invalid because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, t-sql, group-by

I have such code, which works fine:

```
select count (CAST(faculty AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) as num
from student
group by CAST(faculty AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

`faculty` is a text. But I need to count the number of faculty  in a column, so tried this code, which give the error: *Column 'student.faculty' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

```
select faculty, count (CAST(faculty AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) as num
from student
group by CAST(faculty AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

I cant understand, where is the problem, because same method works fine with numbers. For example this one:

```
select id, count(id)  
from student
group by id
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because `CAST(faculty AS NVARCHAR(MAX))` is not equal to `faculty`

Comment: Is it Oracle or MySQL or TSQL or you have not decided yet?

Comment: @Notulysses no difference, I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because you don't group by the same you select.
`CAST(faculty AS NVARCHAR(MAX))` is not equal to `faculty`. Why not use:

```
select faculty, count (*) as num
from student
group by faculty
```

Comment: Your code won`t work with text, this is why I get such error:`The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.`

Comment: But yes, your explanation is true.

Comment: This code works: `select count(CAST(faculty AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) as num ,
             CAST(faculty AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
from student
group by  CAST(faculty AS NVARCHAR(MAX))`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select count(CAST(faculty AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) as num ,
             CAST(faculty AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) facultys
from student
group by facultys
```